# How to generate folder with Lazy Loading Prefix (+) using angular cli?

Tags: angular, directory, lazy-loading, prefix, angular-cli

We began to rewrite our **angular 2** app using mainly **angular-cli** to generate components etc.

The Problem now is, in order to adhere to the Style Guide, major component folders, which later may be loaded lazily should be prefixed with a `"+"`.

Using `--help` of the cli generate instruction I could see two options :

```
--prefix
--route.
```

But setting these to true had no effect on the generated folder name.

My question now is, what is the correct way to generate lazy loaded folders prefixed with a `"+"` using angular-cli ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` was auto-generated when generating routes which is currently disabled as the new router integration is being added.

That being said the style guide is likely going to be updated to remove that suggestion as a few web servers are having issues with that character.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will remove the "+" prefix from all foldernames for now.