# Angular 4 Routes meaning of plus and sharp symbol in augular starter?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Repo is https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter

[image]

I saw all these `+` and `#` for referencing inside `loadChildren` as well as naming inside the folder...

Went to angular reference https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildren saw NOTHING about these sort of convention.

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure why it was voted down? I don't know what the + means here either ... but the hash (#) is part of the loadChildren syntax. It separates the path to the lazy loaded module from the class name of the lazy loaded module.

Comment: @DeborahK Thanks for commenting! Yea, we still got trolls these days, what can you do? Anyway, it is nice to know there is such thing as lazy loaded module, still new to angular 2! Feel free to post the answer, I think if that's the case, + may just be a additional path ppl like to put for ... child indicator? But I certainly will +1 your answer if you just do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash (#) is part of the loadChildren syntax. It separates the path to the lazy loaded module from the class name of the lazy loaded module. Here is an example:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
            {
                path: 'products',
                canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
                data: { preload: true },
                loadChildren: 'app/products/product.module#ProductModule'
            },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
        ]
    ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The + may just be a symbol used in the folder name. I have not seen that usage before but it may mean something to that particular team.

Comment: `+` is used to show that the folder contains lazy loaded module. But seems it is deprecated now

Comment: @yurzui thats interesting! Where you heard that it is deprecated? What symbol they use now instead?

Comment: @Ezeewei It was in style guide early https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639895/how-to-generate-folder-with-lazy-loading-prefix-using-angular-cli

Comment: @Ezeewei https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/b21c90c358129efdd55da897fb7756d44f3b65ae/public/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.jade#L1252 `Prefix Lazy Loaded Folders with +`